# Maximum flights out of a single city for a day

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I am a aviation geek and try to figure out the maximum number of flights that I can take out of a single city. I was able to obtain a dataframe that contains all the flight schedule arriving or departing a city and trying to figure out an efficient way of running the code. The details of the algorithm are follows:

1. Dataframe contains column of flight departing time, arriving time, departing city, arriving city

- Departure Time: DPTR_TIME
- Arriving Time: ARRV_TIME
- Departure City: ORIG
- Arriving City: DEST

2. The city I am currently in is identified as HUB. All flights leaving the hub will take the next flights back to the hub. (For example, if my hub is New York and I am taking New York to Pittsburgh. My next flight will be the Pittsburgh to New York)
3. You can start the day outside of the hub, i.e., fly into the hub and fly out
4. The departure time of the next flight must be greater than the arriving time of the previous flight
5. The dataframe is already sorted by the departing time of the flights

Here's my first approach to the problem:

```
def iter_func(df,sch,conex):
    flt = df.iloc[0]
    df = sch[(sch['ORIG']==flt.DEST) & (sch['DPTR_TIME']>flt.ARRV_TIME+timedelta(hours=conex))]
    if df.shape[0]==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + iter_func(df,test,conex)
```

The function read in the initial flight schedule of the city and pick the first flight. Then it will create another dataframe which start with the city that I fly in and make sure that I am able to connect to the next flight. As you can see this code only output the possible flights for the first flight from from the original schedule.

I am aiming to return a list of flight that contains the most possible flight out of a city in a single day.

Comment: How about adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a _small_ example of input data and the corresponding expected result? IIUC, the solution to this is quite simple and a greedy algorithm will do, but different than what you propose.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, here is a simple way to approach this.

First, we generate "roundtrips", i.e. feasible trips from the hub to another airport and back ("feasible" trips are those that leave the remote airport after the first leg is complete). For a given outbound flight, we chose the one that comes back the soonest. Note that it is not necessarily "the first flight back", as duration may vary for a given route: for example, you may have an outbound flight to JFK that lands at 10am, and then 2 flights backs, one departing at 10:30 and arriving back home at 1pm, the second departing at 10:35 but arriving earlier at 12:50pm.

Second, we select the longest feasible sequence of rountrips, i.e. such that a roundtrip has to be complete before the next one can start. That sequence is the one that greedily selects the first rountrip by return time, then the second one that leaves after that time and, again, comes back soonest, etc.

In both of these steps, a greedy approach guarantees that we find a global optimum:

1. In the first step, there is no advantage to select a roundtrip for a given first leg 'X' that would come back later than the one we chose (the first to come back).
2. In the second step, there is no advantage in selecting a next roundtrip that would come back later than the one we chose (again, the first to come back).

##### Fake flight data generator

To experiment with this, we write a random generator of fake flight data. The only requirement is that `ARRV_TIME > DPTR_TIME`. We won't concern ourselves with making a plausible arrangement of cities such that distances satisfy the triangle inequality or that flight time is roughly consistent with distance.

```py
def gen_random_flights(n, m, t0='2020-01-01', hub='hub'):
    # random airport flight data:
    #   random made-up destinations, random durations
    #   (one-way duration can be totally diff. than return flight)
    # n: number of "other" airports
    # m: number of flights
    airports = pd.unique(
        np.random.randint(65, 65+26, 2*n * 3, dtype=np.uint32).view(f'U3')
    )[:n]  # other airports
    t0 = pd.Timestamp(t0)
    starts = np.random.uniform(size=m + 1).cumsum()
    starts = (pd.to_timedelta(starts / starts[-1], 'day')[:-1] + t0).round('min')

    dur = pd.to_timedelta(pd.Series(np.random.randint(30, 4*60, size=m)), 'min')
    is_dept = np.random.choice([False, True], size=m)
    other_airport = np.random.choice(airports, m)

    flight_num = pd.unique(np.random.randint(0, 10000, 2*m))[:m]
    flight_airline = np.random.choice(['UA', 'AS', 'NZ', 'AC', 'AA', 'VA', 'LH'], m)
    flight_num = [f'{name}{i}' for name, i in zip(flight_airline, flight_num)]

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'flight': flight_num,
        'DPTR_TIME': starts,
        'ARRV_TIME': starts + dur,
        'ORIG': np.where(is_dept, hub, other_airport),
        'DEST': np.where(is_dept, other_airport, hub),
    })
    return df
```

For example:

```py
np.random.seed(163)  # chosen for more interesting data
df = gen_random_flights(2, 10)
>>> df
   flight           DPTR_TIME           ARRV_TIME ORIG DEST
0  NZ1149 2020-01-01 02:48:00 2020-01-01 03:37:00  hub  BOH
1    UA70 2020-01-01 04:51:00 2020-01-01 08:04:00  BOH  hub
2  LH3995 2020-01-01 05:27:00 2020-01-01 08:05:00  hub  BOH
3  AS7420 2020-01-01 07:04:00 2020-01-01 10:29:00  hub  BOH
4  UA2777 2020-01-01 08:18:00 2020-01-01 08:50:00  hub  PCH
5  VA3028 2020-01-01 09:09:00 2020-01-01 10:22:00  PCH  hub
6  AA1217 2020-01-01 12:12:00 2020-01-01 13:00:00  hub  BOH
7  AA8825 2020-01-01 15:02:00 2020-01-01 16:39:00  BOH  hub
8  LH9857 2020-01-01 17:36:00 2020-01-01 20:01:00  PCH  hub
9  LH5359 2020-01-01 20:53:00 2020-01-01 23:40:00  hub  PCH
```

The airport codes and flight numbers are of course random.

##### Make roundtrips

As mentioned above, the algorithm here is simply to select, for any outbound flight, the first feasible returning flight *by arrival time*.

```py
def make_roundtrips(df, hub='hub'):
    is_outb = df['ORIG'] == hub
    is_back = df['DEST'] == hub

    a = df.loc[is_outb]
    b = df.loc[is_back]

    z = a.merge(
        b, left_on='DEST', right_on='ORIG',
        suffixes=['', '_ret']
    ).query('ARRV_TIME < DPTR_TIME_ret').sort_values('ARRV_TIME_ret')
    z = z.groupby('DPTR_TIME', sort=False).first().reset_index()
    
    return z[[
        'flight', 'DPTR_TIME', 'ARRV_TIME', 'DEST',
        'flight_ret', 'DPTR_TIME_ret', 'ARRV_TIME_ret',
    ]]
```

Example on our fake data above:

```py
z = make_roundtrips(df)
>>> z
   flight           DPTR_TIME           ARRV_TIME DEST flight_ret       DPTR_TIME_ret       ARRV_TIME_ret
0  NZ1149 2020-01-01 02:48:00 2020-01-01 03:37:00  BOH       UA70 2020-01-01 04:51:00 2020-01-01 08:04:00
1  UA2777 2020-01-01 08:18:00 2020-01-01 08:50:00  PCH     VA3028 2020-01-01 09:09:00 2020-01-01 10:22:00
2  LH3995 2020-01-01 05:27:00 2020-01-01 08:05:00  BOH     AA8825 2020-01-01 15:02:00 2020-01-01 16:39:00
3  AS7420 2020-01-01 07:04:00 2020-01-01 10:29:00  BOH     AA8825 2020-01-01 15:02:00 2020-01-01 16:39:00
4  AA1217 2020-01-01 12:12:00 2020-01-01 13:00:00  BOH     AA8825 2020-01-01 15:02:00 2020-01-01 16:39:00
```

##### Selecting the longest sequence of roundtrips

Now that we have narrowed down the interesting roundtrips, we can greedily select the first one by returning (arrival) time, then the next one after that, etc.

```py
def select_roundtrips(z):
    t = z['DPTR_TIME'].min() - pd.Timedelta(1)
    z = z.sort_values('ARRV_TIME_ret')  # just to make sure
    ix = []
    while True:
        cond = z['DPTR_TIME'] > t
        if not cond.any():
            break
        i = z.loc[cond].index[0]
        ix.append(i)
        t = z.loc[i, 'ARRV_TIME_ret']
    return z.loc[ix]
```

Continuing with our fake example above:

```py
>>> select_roundtrips(z)
   flight           DPTR_TIME           ARRV_TIME DEST flight_ret       DPTR_TIME_ret       ARRV_TIME_ret
0  NZ1149 2020-01-01 02:48:00 2020-01-01 03:37:00  BOH       UA70 2020-01-01 04:51:00 2020-01-01 08:04:00
1  UA2777 2020-01-01 08:18:00 2020-01-01 08:50:00  PCH     VA3028 2020-01-01 09:09:00 2020-01-01 10:22:00
4  AA1217 2020-01-01 12:12:00 2020-01-01 13:00:00  BOH     AA8825 2020-01-01 15:02:00 2020-01-01 16:39:00
```

##### Speed

What about performance on more realistic data size? Won't that cross-join be very expensive?

The size of the join is indeed O(p^2), where p is the maximum number of flights between our hub and a given airport. In practice, even with busy airports, this is actually small.

On fake data, the method behaves quite well. Example:

```py
df = gen_random_flights(50, 2500)
%timeit select_roundtrips(make_roundtrips(df))
26.1 ms ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```